# Media Query overriding other media query only on Safari/iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, css, sass, media-queries

I have this issue where my media queries are messing up on my iPhone and iPad, my tablet media query is targeted on my iPhone so the layout on mobile is all wrong.

I have already checked my ordering of the media queries, and they are from smallest to biggest since as I styled the page starting from mobile view first.

```
.career-feature-icon {
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
        padding: 10px;

        @media screen and (min-width: 37.5rem) {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
        }

        @media (min-width: 64rem) {
            width: 25%;
        }

        img {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        h2 {
            text-align: center;

            @media (min-width: 64rem) {
                padding-top: 20px;
            }
        }
    }
```

My styling is there, but it is overruled by whatever is in the 37.5rem media query.

Again this is *ONLY* on iOS devices, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED: I changed my media query from REM to px `37.5rem -> 600px` `64rem -> 1024px` and it rendered the way it should

Answer (score 0):

```
/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px (48rem to 64rem)
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px (30.065rem to 47.93rem)
*/

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Most of the Smartphones Mobiles (Portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 320px to 480px (20rem to 30rem)
*/

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

  //CSS

}
```

Try this might work

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am coding mobile first, so the mobile styling doesn't have a media query, but the tablet and desktop styling does. Im also using SASS not purely CSS, have you ever experienced issues with styling just on iOS?

Comment: Above code is just sample media query, to avoid complications. Try to implement media qurey for mobile devices and check view port is assigned.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it looks like when I changed my media queries from REM to px, it rendered the way it should :)